# Terraform, how to ignore failed servers while provisioning?

Tags: provisioning, terraform

I am running terraform with a private openstack cloud to bootstrap new servers.  When I try to create new servers (using any method) during the busiest times of operation (weekdays in the afternoon) usually half of the servers fail (and this has nothing to do with terraform).  The issue is when one of the servers I try to provision fails to complete a `provisioner "remote-exec"` block without errors (because of my private cloud) my whole `terraform apply` stops.

I want terraform to totally ignore these failed servers when I run `terraform apply` so that if I try to provision 20 server and only 1 of them launches successfully, then that one server will run through all the commands I specify in my resource block.

Is there something like an `ignore_failed_resources = true` line I can add to my resources so that terraform will ignore the servers that fail and run the successful ones to completion?

Comment: There's not really any way to do that in TF (as far as I know). You could try unbundling the Terraform and the provisioning and have something external do the provisioning after TF has completed. We have TF create instances and then separately run Ansible playbooks against the new instances and orchestrate all of that via Jenkins. Adds a bit of complexity to the whole thing but means you aren't so tightly coupled like you are here.

Comment: Hi ! The same idea as with previous comment. Try [sparrowform](https://github.com/melezhik/sparrowform), a lightweight provision tool for terraform based infrastructure. It's decoupled from terraform, so this handles your case with provisioning errors.

Answer (score 2):

There's no simple config switch that you can enable to achieve this. Could you be more specific about the problem that's causing the "remote-exec" to fail?

If it's because it's simply refusing to connect, you could switch out your "remote-exec" for a "local-exec" and wrap your command in a script, passing in the hostname of your server as a parameter. The script would then handle initiating the SSH connection and running the required commands. Make sure the script fails gracefully with an exit code of 0 if the error occurs, so that terraform will think that the script worked correctly.

```
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
    provisioner "local-exec" {
        command = "./myremotecommand.sh ${aws_instance.web.private_ip}"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you already figured out a solution, but adding my solution here for anyone who will encounter this in the future.

Why not simply do in the command part this?

```
provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "my command || true"
}
```

This way, it'll always return code 0, so if the shell ignore the failure, terraform will ignore it as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at terraform local provisioner doc
you can put `on_failure = continue`
So it will continue at failure.